# OKTA SCIM tests - “Required Test: Create Okta user with realisitic values” does not have a Content-Type

Tags: okta, scim

I downloaded OKTA default test suite from, http://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/SCIMFiles/Okta-SCIM-20-SPEC-Test.json.  I uploaded this to Runscope and tried to execute tests (I am referring to line number 782 in this json file.)

I noticed that “**Required Test: Create Okta user with realisitic values**” test case in OKTA SCIM default test which is a POST request to Create user resource (“Required Test: Create Okta user with realisitic values”  POST  {{SCIMBaseURL}}/Users) **does not have Content-Type** (In Line 782 in attached json file). 
Is this intended or it's a bug?
When the “Content-Type” is not presented in the request, our SCIM Api returns Http Status Code 415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting up at template SCIM app in an [Okta developer edition](https://www.okta.com/developer/signup/) org and see what it sends as a `Content-Type` header, then modify your Runscope tests to use that header.

I also recommend that you open a ticket with developers@okta.com so you can get more personalized help on your integration.